# Parametric curve: $x=\frac{a}{2}(t+\frac{1}{t})$, $y=\frac{b}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})$?

Tags: vector-analysis, parametric

What kind of shape is the parametric curve described by:

$$x=\frac{a}{2}(t+\frac{1}{t})$$
$$y=\frac{b}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})$$

$a,b \in\mathbb{R^+}$

?

Comment: $(\frac x a)^2-(\frac y b)^2=1$ - a hyperbola.

Comment: You can also replace $t$ with $e^z$ then you will get classical parametric equation for hyperbola $x=a ~\cosh (z), ~y=b~ \sinh (z)$

Comment: What's the key for seeing these equations are of the form of a hyperbola? I mean, where does one figure out to "replace $t$ with something"?

Comment: @mavavilj Divide the first equation by $a$ and divide the second by $b$ to re-scale properly. Think of some operations on these two equations that will get rid of $t$ on the right hand side. Notice that squaring both equations and subtracting eliminates $t$. Show that you didn't create any new cases when squaring. Done. Alternatively, solve the first equation for $t$ (quadratic) and substitute into the second.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $t=e^u$ for $t>0$, and $t=-e^u$ for $t<0$, then use $\cosh^2u-\sinh^2u=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A set of hyperbolas with x-, y- axes as symmetry axes.

Although not asked for, the above can be seen as projections of a surface for each of two parameters, one extra parameter can be brought in.

To connect further to paraboloids, a 3D parametrization is necessary with $two$ parameters.

$$ x=\dfrac{u}{2}(t+\frac{1}{t})  ; y=\dfrac{u}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t}) ; z = u ;$$